# Face tracker with 3D filters in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

My application requires a face tracking with 3D filters module just like snapchat. After all searching i am able to track faces with all landmarks using [Google Vision Api](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) . Although i am able to set some 2D filters on faces but could not find a way to apply 3D filters. Does anyone have some solution to my problem??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this is relevant to the Cloud Platform itself. I would suggest to look into the AR technology and find the proper SDK/Library for it --> e.g. https://deepar.ai/

Comment: Did you get any progress on this.

Comment: Use sceneform, it’s free and fast